# How to disable persistence

Tags: jpa

I'm developing a REST service with JPA support...
I have the need to deploy the service on the server with the persistence temporarily disabled and in the same time continue to develop with the persistence enabled on my debug environment.
How do I achieve this goal.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled persistence"? That no DB operation (not even `SELECT`) is made at all? Or do not want any modification made in DB? Why do you want that?

Comment: I mean no DB operation at all because don't have already any DB server on target machine but I want that the service is persistence ready.
Hope to be enough clear.

Comment: What should happen with a REST service that makes a request to DB? I think your question makes no sense.

Comment: I understand that the question is a little confused but my service is mixed with volatile requests and requests that  will be persistent in the future,I have all code persistent ready but without any DB server my application crash on startup due missing DB connection.
Now I want to start to give only "volatile" service but when the DB server become available turn on persistence and ready to go.

Comment: Why not simply rename the persistence.xml file to persistence_not_user.xml if you build for production?